# Querying and saving an XML document

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have coded a console application asking the user to enter the name of a specific persona in the hamlet play. If the name the user gives is valid, the user is requested to select whether he/she wants to save;

1. Only the acts the persona is part of;
2. Only the acts and scenes the persona is part of;
3. Only the lines the persona is part of; OR
4. The entire script for that persona (ie. acts, scenes and lines)

After the user has selected an option, the program saves the output to an xml document named "persona.xml".

Below is my method for option 4, saving an xml document with the persona's acts, scenes and lines. I have successfully adjusted this method to get the correct output for option 1 and 2. However, I am unable to display the lines only for option 3. Please can someone advise me on how I could adjust this method? Many thanks.

```
private static void CreateAndSaveXML_Lines() throws Exception {
    // query the document and save out nodes that match a specified criteria
    // create document
    Document outputDoc = createDoc();
    // create root element and attach to document
    Element results = outputDoc.createElement("lines");
    results.setAttribute("speaker", persona);
    outputDoc.appendChild(results);

    // Find all acts
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//ACT[SCENE/SPEECH/SPEAKER = '" + persona + "']");
    NodeList personaActs = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    // Find all scenes
    expr = xpath.compile("//SCENE[SPEECH/SPEAKER = '" + persona + "']");
    NodeList personaScenes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    // Find all speeches
    expr = xpath.compile("//SPEECH[SPEAKER = '" + persona + "']");
    NodeList personaSpeeches = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    // Find all lines
    expr = xpath.compile("//SPEECH[SPEAKER = '" + persona + "']/LINE");
    NodeList personaLines = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

    int actCount = 0;
    int sceneCount = 0;
    int speechCount = 0;
    int lineCount = 0;

    while (actCount < personaActs.getLength())
    {
        Element actNode = addNewElement(outputDoc, "act", results, "title", personaActs.item(actCount).getChildNodes().item(0).getTextContent());
        while (sceneCount < personaScenes.getLength()&& personaActs.item(actCount) == personaScenes.item(sceneCount).getParentNode())
        {
            Element sceneNode = addNewElement(outputDoc, "scene", actNode, "title", personaScenes.item(sceneCount).getChildNodes().item(0).getTextContent());
            while (speechCount < personaSpeeches.getLength()&& personaScenes.item(sceneCount) == personaSpeeches.item(speechCount).getParentNode())
            {
                Element speechNode = addNewElement(outputDoc, "speech", results, "id", Integer.toString(speechCount+1));
                while (lineCount < personaLines.getLength() && personaSpeeches.item(speechCount) == personaLines.item(lineCount).getParentNode())
                {
                    Node lineNode = personaLines.item(lineCount).cloneNode(true);
                    outputDoc.adoptNode(lineNode);
                    speechNode.appendChild(lineNode);
                    lineCount++;
                }
                speechCount++;
            }
            sceneCount++;
        }
        actCount++;
    }

    // get old root
    saveDoc(outputDoc, persona + ".xml");
}
```